# DOORS : Import spreadsheet and update contents using DXL

Tags: ibm-doors

I have a spreadsheet(csv file) that needs to be imported to DOORS module. The problem is that I have to append the contents of a specific attribute (instead of replacing it).

For Example :

A) Lets say an object "ExampleObject" has an attribute "ExampleAttribute" with values :

Value 1

Value 2

B) and the Spreadsheet has "Value 3" for "ExampleAttribute" of "ExampleObject".

C) When imported, "ExampleAttribute" of "ExampleObject" should be updated to:

Value 1

Value 2

Value 3

Answer (score 1):

I think, the easiest approach would be to create a temporary attribute "ExampleAttributeTemp". You would import the content of the column to this temporary attribute (with a simple "overwrite attribute"). After the import has finished, you would have a small script like

```
Object o
Module m = current
for o in entire m do {
   if o."ExampleAttributeTemp" != "" then {
      o."ExampleAttribute" = o."ExampleAttribute" "\n" o."ExampleAttributeTemp" ""
      o."ExampleAttributeTemp" = ""
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Mike. This solution makes sense. I'll try it out.